# I don't know how division works in SQL SERVER(Using NOT EXISTS... (NOT EXISTS) )

Tags: sql, relational-division, not-exists

I have 3 tables

```
PRODUCT          
    ID  -------COUNTRY    
    1   --------Singapore  
    2   --------VietNam   
    3   --------Singapor   
    4   --------Campuchia
RECEIPT
IDPRO -------IDBILL
    1 -------A
    2 -------B
    3 -------A
    3 -------C
    4 -------B
BILL 
   CODE 
    A
    B
    C
```

The question my teacher ask:list all CODE
bought all products from Singapore

This is his answer:

```
SELECT CODE
FROM BILL B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT P
WHERE COUNTRY='Singagpore' and not exists(
SELECT * FROM RECEIPT R
WHERE B.CODE=R.IDBILL AND P.ID=R.IDPRO))
```

It works prefectly
The result is: A

The problem is that when I run the command line of the subquery, there are no results

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT P
    WHERE COUNTRY='Singagpore' and not exists(
    SELECT * FROM RECEIPT R
    WHERE  P.ID=R.IDPRO)
```

Suppose the above result is assigned K.

the rest of the command line will be:

```
SELECT CODE
FROM BILL B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (K)
```

How can it get any result like my teacher did while it uses empty results as reference?

I have searched for how to use `NOT EXISTS`, but in division it kinda hard

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. PS Saying you researched is not helpful. Put what is relevant to asking in your post, quoting with credit ,& integrate into asking your 1 question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[bill] (
    [code]  VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL    
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[product] (
    [product_id]    INT         NOT NULL,
    [country]   VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[receipt] (
    [receipt_id]    INT         NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [product_id]    INT         NOT NULL,
    [bill_id]   VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO bill (code) values ('A')
INSERT INTO bill (code) values ('B')
INSERT INTO bill (code) values ('C')

INSERT INTO product (product_id, country) values (1,'Singapore')
INSERT INTO product (product_id, country) values (2,'VietNam')
INSERT INTO product (product_id, country) values (3,'Singapore')
INSERT INTO product (product_id, country) values (4,'Campuchia')      
INSERT INTO receipt (product_id, bill_id) values (1,'A')
INSERT INTO receipt (product_id, bill_id) values (2,'B')
INSERT INTO receipt (product_id, bill_id) values (3,'A')
INSERT INTO receipt (product_id, bill_id) values (3,'C')
INSERT INTO receipt (product_id, bill_id) values (4,'B')
```

Returns A:

```
SELECT code
FROM BILL B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM PRODUCT P
    WHERE COUNTRY='Singapore' and not exists(
        SELECT * FROM RECEIPT R
        WHERE B.CODE=R.bill_id AND P.product_id=R.product_id))
```

This is because the code in the NOT EXISTS clause will run for every row in BILL and if the select returns nothing the row will be selected. If the select returns something then it will not be selected. The reverse will happen if you use EXISTS instead of NOT EXISTS. This returns nothing for A, so A will be returned:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT P
WHERE COUNTRY='Singapore' and not exists(
    SELECT * FROM RECEIPT R
    WHERE 'A'=R.bill_id AND P.product_id=R.product_id)
```

Returns something for B, so B will not be returned:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT P
WHERE COUNTRY='Singapore' and not exists(
    SELECT * FROM RECEIPT R
    WHERE 'B'=R.bill_id AND P.product_id=R.product_id)
```

Returns something for C, so C will not be returned:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT P
WHERE COUNTRY='Singapore' and not exists(
    SELECT * FROM RECEIPT R
    WHERE 'C'=R.bill_id AND P.product_id=R.product_id)
```

Comment: Please put Q&A explanations in prose, not in code. Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Please indent code reasonably per syntax & semantics. PS Helpful code comments & documentation say why given code was written in terms of the application or internal interfaces when that's not obvious/straightforward.

Comment: it will run as a loop with the number of iterations equal to the number of rows. Thank you, i get it